# inflammatory independent pseudo-essay-journal

Tags: meaning

What does "inflammatory independent pseudo-essay-journal" in this passage mean?

> getting into god but not in an ironic post-irony problematic alt-lit
> neo-edgelord inflammatory independent pseudo-essay-jornal catholic
> living in babylon trad wojak girl type of way but like a sincere
> posting non-accelerationism anti-trad de-institutionalizing believer
> of the eternal battle between good and evil driving the engine of
> spiritual history post-church hate the anti-christ kind of way

Source: https://ifunny.co/picture/G5vsvEMq8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole passage is little more than gobbledegook (intentionally, as it is intended humourously), but you can analyse the fragment you quoted:

- It is describing a journal.
- The journal is formatted in a way that makes its contents look as if
  they are essays (but, in some way, do not qualify as such).
- The journal is not affiliated in any way (to no group, company,
  religion, political party, etc.)
- The contents of the journal are intended to inflame.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I see, so the person is saying that he/she is not the type of  person who runs/writes such a journal?

Comment: no no no.  The joke is that these "ways of getting into god" are ridiculously complex and ultimately meaningless.  It's funny, because it laughs **at** people who try to analyse faith like this.  If you try to understand what the person is saying, you are missing the whole point of the joke, which is that there is nothing to understand!